# Is it possible to construct a ProcessStartInfo from an already running process?

Tags: c#, .net

If I *connect* to a running process by extracting it using `Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");`, is it possible to reconstruct that process´s *ProcessStartInfo*?

I would for example want to be able to attach to *Notepad*, *Kill* it and *Start* it again. Without a valid *ProcessStartInfo* the *Start* call will fail.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct support for this.

You can go over each property of the running process and initialize a `ProcessStartInfo` object with the corresponding values.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are cases where that's not possible.  A simple example is:

```
 Process.Start("example.lnk");
```

No way to find out later that a .lnk file was used to get the process started.

The WorkingDirectory is a tricky one, a process often requires it to be set correctly but might change it later.  A process that got started with a different user account is insurmountable, no way you can provide the correct account password.  A custom environment is yet another one.